# Convergence of sequence and series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show that if $a_n$ is a convergent **series** of non-negative reals such that {$a_n$} is decreasing for all n, then the **sequence** $na_n$ converges to 0.

*My attempt:*

If series $a_n$ converges, then root test would imply that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq1$.

**Case 1:$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}<1$**

Applying root test on sequence $b_n=na_n$ would imply that $\lim_{n\to\infty}({na_n})^{\frac{1}{n}}<1$.
Hence series $b_n$ converges. Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty}{na_n}=0$.

**Case 2:**$\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$

**I need help to proceed with this case.**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, I am looking for help in case 2.

Comment: The many duplicates provide a complete proof without the need to break it into those case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

$\sum a_n $ converges $ \implies $

$$\lim S_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}+\cdots a_{2n})=0$$

but

$$0<na_{2n}<S_n$$
since $(a_n)$ is decreasing.

So
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}2na_{2n}=0$$

Do the same for $ (2n+1)a_{2n+1}$